# ask for help in finding an idiom or expression

Tags: idioms

have you ever faced with this situation? You suggest people to do something but they reject it! after a while the other people suggest the same thing and they accept! can you tell me any expression or idiom that can be used in this situation?

Comment: Could you please give us an example sentence with a series of blanks for the missing expression? But as things stand right now, one possible expression that I could recommend would be **he changed his mind**.

Answer (score 1):

A common expression to say as the person making suggestions is simply

> **(S)he never listens to me.**

and could be used in

> **Why don't you suggest it to** *someone* **they never listen to me.**

Answer (score 0):

I may say that. They rejected my idea. However, they came around when Tom (or someone else) told that idea to them. 
Come around = change their mind

Answer (score 0):

It might not be exactly what you look for, but this might fit:

> Some people have [**double standards**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/double-standard%5C).
>
> **double standard** (noun) = a rule or standard of good behaviour that, unfairly, some people are expected to follow or achieve but other people are not:
>
> - The governor is being accused of (having) **double standards** in being tough on law and order yet allowing his own cabinet members to escape prosecution for fraud.